# Why postRotate() method change X axis direction

Tags: java, android, matrix, android-canvas

I'm trying to reflect a drawn sticker like this

**Original Sticker** ---------- **Reflected Sticker**

```
      ↓                           ↓
```

[image]

```
public void reflectCurrentSticker(int windowWidth) {

    //     Y
    // ----|----- x
    //     |

    //creation of the cloned sticker
    //getWidth() == width of the FrameLayout (where the stickers drawn)

    Matrix originalMatrix = getReflectedMatrix(getWidth(), originalSticker);
    addSticker(clonedSticker);
    clonedSticker.setMatrix(originalMatrix);
    invalidate();

}

public Matrix getReflectedMatrix(int wrapperWidth, Sticker sticker) {
    Matrix matrix = sticker.getMatrix();
    float transX = getMatrixValue(matrix, 2);
    float transY = getMatrixValue(matrix, 5);
    float newX = (((float) wrapperWidth) - transX) - ((float) sticker.getCurrentWidth());
    float currentAngle = sticker.getCurrentAngle();
    float currentScale = sticker.getCurrentScale();
    Matrix newMatrix = new Matrix();
    newMatrix.postRotate(currentAngle);
    newMatrix.postScale(currentScale, currentScale);
    newMatrix.postTranslate(newX, transY);
    return newMatrix;
}

public float getMatrixValue(@NonNull Matrix matrix, @IntRange(from = 0, to = 9) int valueIndex) {
        final float[] matrixValues = new float[9];
        matrix.getValues(matrixValues);
        return matrixValues[valueIndex];
}
```

My code works fine, but the issue starts when I rotate the original sticker, and try to create a reflected sticker from it, unfortunately, I got this, the reflected sticker positioned in the wrong place, with the wrong rotation angle.

**Original Sticker** -- **Reflected Sticker**

```
      ↓                 ↓
```

[image]

The expected output is :

**Original Sticker** ---------- **Reflected Sticker**

```
      ↓                           ↓
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> Why postRotate() method change X axis direction?

It might look like it is, it is not. First at all, you need to understand that `translate()`, `rotate()` and `screw()` operations require a pivot point. The pivot point is at the most top-left of any image/bitmap.
Secondly, Android always rotate an image/bitmap clockwisely and not anti-clockwise. If you want to rotate it anti-clockwise, you could negate the angle e.i. `90` to `-90` but it is not recommended -- it might causes bugs. Rather `360 - angle - 180`.
So, this is probably what you wanted.

```java
newMatrix.postScale(-currentScale, currentScale);
newMatrix.postTranslate(sticker.getCurrentWidth, transY);
newMatrix.postRotate(360 - currentAngle - 180);
```

Comment: Massive thanks for taking the time to answer my question, unfortunately, it's not working, in fact, the reflected sticker is positioned in the wrong place now, I don't have any issue with scale and transX, so I don't know why you change it in your code, however thank yo again